# How to use css to layout a number of dynamically appeared buttons evenly?

Tags: css, vue.js

I have a number of buttons that are generated in Vue using v-if dynamically. I want to layout the buttons evenly on the bottom of the page (left and right space areas are the same).

I'm using the mdui button style, it appears to be fixed width and height. So I have to layout on one row ( for example if there are less than three or four buttons or exceed the mobile page's width) or two rows (if there are more buttons)

I have tried `<div class="bottomBtn" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;">` It's not working... I'm very confused about div boxes. How to achieve this?

[image]

I expect the left and right spaces are even. But the result is shown in the picture, all the buttons are left aligned...

```
<div class="bottomBtn">
<button class="mdui-btn mdui-btn-raised">Save</button>
<button class="mdui-btn mdui-btn-raised" v-if="pullDisplay">PullBack</button>
<button class="mdui-btn mdui-btn-raised" v-if="cancelDisplay">Cancel</button>
<button class="mdui-btn mdui-btn-raised" v-if="reviseDisplay">Revise</button>
<button class="mdui-btn mdui-btn-raised" v-if="sendDisplay">SendBack</button>
<button class="mdui-btn mdui-btn-raised" v-if="approvalDisplay">Approval</button>
</div>
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? How does your intended behaviour differ from what you get? What CSS is attached to the `bottomBtn` class? See also: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @rh16 I have add a picture. I expect the left and right spaces are even, and possibly some spaces between the buttons. But the result is shown in the picture, all the buttons are left aligned...

Comment: @rh16 Thanks for the guide. I add the <div class="bottomBtn" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;justify-content:space-around">, it looks good now!

Comment: Haha just posted an answer suggesting `space-between`. Same general idea, slightly different result so a matter of preference which gives the look you were most closely going for.

Answer (score 0):

To use flexbox to achieve this, as it seems you are trying, you need to set the  `justify-content` property to `space-between`.

i.e

```
<div class="bottomBtn" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; justify-content: space-between;">
```

I would also recommend collecting these styles into a class that can be added into a div.

`space-around` and `space-evenly` can also be used for a similar effect, so you might want to try each and see which give you the result you are most happy with.

I highly recommend [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for figuring out how to get flexbox to do exactly what you want in the future.

Final recommendation: If you want there always to be a gap between the buttons (so that they wrap before they are fully touching) just add a left and right margin to the buttons and flex will take care of the rest.